# How do I add a check interval to my code to change a div on a certain date?

Tags: javascript, date, timer

My working code:

```
if (new Date() < new Date(2013,3,25)) {
   document.getElementById("StatusOn").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("StatusOff").style.display = "none";
} else {
   document.getElementById("StatusOn").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("StatusOff").style.display = "block";
}
```

How do I add this check interval to the code above?

```
// call the "check ..." function every 10 seconds.
//setInterval("check_if_it_is_some_date_today()", 10000);
```

Comment: Wrap it all in a function and then put that function in the `setInterval` call?

Comment: You appear to have pasted in two identical blocks of code btw - maybe edit your question?

Comment: Yea i seen the code twice I tried to edit it but it's only showing me that i pasted the code there once... ???

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a function, which is what you should be passing to `setInterval` anyway:

```
setInterval(function() {
    if (new Date() < new Date(2013,3,25)) {
        document.getElementById("StatusOn").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("StatusOff").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("StatusOn").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("StatusOff").style.display = "block";
    }
}, 10000);
```

Comment: I tried that but for some reason it's not working... do you know why?

Comment: @Steve: No. Post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), please. (Also, why the downvote, whoever did it? I appreciate a comment.)

Comment: "it's not working... do you know why" - not without further information. I would encourage you to do more debugging, rather than giving up and asking immediately. The former makes for good practise, whilst the latter won't teach you anything.